# Visual Tooling for apache camel

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, integration, esb, jbossfuse

Can I develop apache camel routes using Jboss developer studio or it is only to be used when we use Jboss Fuse ESB?

Previously I saw that Fuse IDE could be used for Camel development, but now I don't find it anymore.

Comment: plz update if u have solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes JBoss Tools for Apache Camel can be used for JBoss Fuse and as well Apache Camel. Fuse IDE is the former name, its now known part of JBoss Tools. You can install JBoss Tools in Eclipse and then install the integration tools that has the Camel editor.

- http://tools.jboss.org/features/apachecamel.html